# how to have text between an HR line

Tags: html, css

How can I have my text between an `<HR>` line?

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/VrvvX/

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <button id="myButton">Do This</button>
    <br>-----------or do something else-<br>
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td>Blah:</td>
            <td><select id="foo"></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Blah:</td>
            <td><select id="foo"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>​
```

Rather than having `-----` I'd like to have a pretty `<hr>` tag which works like a separator between the `button` and the `table`.

Comment: Why not just wrap the hr in a div that has its with specified? The hr fills the width of the div, so you can fill 100% of any width you choose. E.g:     <div style='width: 5.5em; display: inline-block;'><hr></div>

Answer (score 3):

Set two `<hr/>` tags to `display: inline-block` and put a `width` on them with the text in between. [Like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrvvX/143/). Though you [may want to adjust the positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/VrvvX/145/) of it.

Comment: very weird bit looks like it answers the question +1

Comment: I have done something like this but using `hr:after{ content:"some text"; }` but of course, this is a better solution

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tomás solution, you could create a HR class and add `content: attr(data-content);` to it. And then use the following HTML `<hr class="hr-1" data-content="CONTENT HERE"/>`.

This way you can fill in the content through HTML rather than CSS.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xqeuzrg7/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
<div style="background: url('line-background.png') 50% 50% repeat-x;width: 100%;text-align: center;">
    Do this
</div>
```

Of course you can adjust width or play with padding: 0 ?px;

EDIT :

If you want to hide background under the title you can do :

```
<div style="background: url('line-background.png') 50% 50% repeat-x;width: 100%;text-align: center;">
   <span style="background: white;padding: 2px;"> Do this</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best practice to do this but you can use this css for the `<hr/>` tag and it will properly work:

```
hr {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top:  1px dashed #CCC;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;    
    font-size:12px;
}
hr:after {
    content:"or do something else";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    top: -0.7em;  
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    background: white;
}​
```

I have updated your example, see if this is what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/VrvvX/146/